Use custom variables from .scss file in a bslib theme
I'm trying to use my own custom palette in my Shiny app built with bslib/Bootstrap but can't figure out how to use the variables I added to root. When inspecting my app page, I'm able to see the custom colors in root (albeit a separate root than where Bootstrap variables are loaded) but can't use them.
Here is a short reprex (of what I tried and doesn't work - replacing "var(--my-color-1")" by "darkblue" for example works):
app.R
library(shiny)
library(sass)
library(bslib)
library(magrittr)

custom_theme <- bslib::bs_theme(version = 5) %>%
    bslib::bs_add_rules(sass::sass_file("www/colors.scss")) %>%
    bslib::bs_add_variables("navbar-dark-bg" = "var(--my-color-1)")

shinyApp(
    ui = bslib::page_navbar(
        title = "My App",
        theme = custom_theme,
        inverse = TRUE, # to use navbar-dark-bg
        bslib::nav_panel(title = "Tab 1"),
        bslib::nav_panel(title = "Tab 2")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {}
)

www/colors.scss
:root {
  --my-color-1: #76b0ff;
  --my-color-2: #ec6453;
}

Edit: using bslib::bs_add_rules() instead of bslib::bs_add_variables() makes var(--my-color-1) usable in the browser inspect menu but can't figure out how to use it in the app code.

Does it work (and suffice) if you set --bs-body-color: #76b0ff; inside your :root?

@FelixJassler it effectively replaces the variable and I can use it in the inspect menu but still can't use it in the code to change default values of Boostrap variables like navbar-dark-bg. I need to change quite a bit of defaults and would like to avoid doing it in css; instead managing it all through the Bootstrap theme.

I don't get what you want here. If you set --bs-body-color: #76b0ff; inside :root and run your script, then the navbar appears blue. This is because --bslib-navbar-inverse-bg is defined as var(--bs-body-color) and this one was overwritten in :root. How shall your app look like if navbar-dark-bg was overwritten (where is it currently used?)?

@Jan I do not want to overwrite bootstrap root variables but rather add my color palette in the root as variables. If I change --bs-body-color's value other elements will be impacted which I do not want to happen.

But aren't you trying to do the same with navbar-dark-bg? What is your goal here? This is currently not used, where do you want to apply it?

@Jan My goal is simply to use my custom palette added in :root and change specific bootstrap variables values to create a bslib theme. Also navbar-dar-bg is defined by $navbar-bg per the documentation and your example (overwriting --bs-body-colordoes not work).

I think that you are missing one really important point here: While you are right that navbar-dark-bg is defined by $navbar-bg, you can see that this defaults to null, i.e., no color currently applies. Also notice that by the documentation this is used for navbarPage() and you nowhere use this in your example. Second, you write that "replacing "var(--my-color-1")" by "darkblue" ... works" - for me not, nothing changes.

All in all you should edit your question and clarify what you want. In particular it is important to understand which variables you want to edit so that in particular it becomes clear where --my-color-1 shall be seen. Also you don't want to overwrite bootstrap root variables because other elements will be impacted but I don't understand what the expectation is if you say navbar-dark-bg" = "var(--my-color-1)" - this is also overwriting something and other elements can be impacted.
